# save Python variables after running it from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, save

I am using python and Visual Studio code to develop my code.  I can run my scripts successfully (Using Run Python File in Terminal). However, this is very inconvenient since after each run I go back to the terminal window and do not have access to python, therefore, I will lose the variables in the previous run so I have three options: 1- Print all the variables I want to screen (This is clearly not scalable). 2- Run the file again. 3- Run the Python file in an interactive window(Ipython).

Option 3 is exactly like running the file in a Jupyter Notebook which is very convenient since you can create a cell below the current cell and keep using the variables after one run.

I would like to know what is the best method to run the python script from the terminal (Pycharm, VS code,...) and can work with variables after (not like every time you forgot to print something you run the file again?

Comment: you can use `python -i myscript.py` to make python open up an interactive interpreter session

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wrote it above. It is option 3 I mentioned. (You can run in an interactive window)

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without running it in interactive mode ?

Comment: To do **what**. It really isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish. Your question is vague. It isn't clear if you are asking about data persistence or what. What are you expecting to be able *to do*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes I am asking about data persistence.

Comment: That is an enormous topic. From simply writing some text to a file to creating a full-fledged data-base server managed across various instances that can communicate with other services at any time. Please understand, that you have some built-in assumptions about *what we understand about your current workflow and needs* that isn't really obvious if you don't elaborate some more about *what exactly you need*.

Comment: Thanks. I am asking any generic code you write and data persistence between run.       I simply wanted to know if there is another easy method that I am missing beside using the interactive python session.

Comment: That is way too broad of a question. There is no "generic" approach to data persistance. That's like asking a question "whats the best way to write this code". *What code*? What is it supposed to accomplish? What are the inputs and desired outputs? etc. In any case, your question doesn't really seem to be about data persistence, since you talk about running your code in VS Code while writing it. So again, it isn't clear **what you are trying to do**.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint then debug your code (f5), on the bottom of VSCode there is a Debug Console, you can type in debug command there (print(), type(), etc). That seems like it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try shift + enter on each line this will open the terminal with python
Or try to run .ipynb files instead of .py files in vscode